# Operation not permitted on IsolatedStorageFileStream Exception

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8

Okay, I have searched and tried every solution possible but still it is throwing exception. Any help would be wonderful.

```
public void SaveOrReplace(string fileContent)
        {
            using (IsolatedStorageFile storage = IsolatedStorageFile.GetUserStoreForApplication())
            {
                if (!storage.DirectoryExists("FX"))
                    storage.CreateDirectory("FX");

                if (storage.FileExists(FilePath))
                    storage.DeleteFile(FilePath);

                //when I debug, it code does not get past here
                // when I remove this first using no exception, but of course I can't write some text to the file
                using (IsolatedStorageFileStream fileStream = storage.CreateFile(FilePath))
                {
                    using (StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(fileStream))
                    {
                        writer.Write(fileContent);
                        fileStream.Dispose();
                    }
                }

            }
        }
```

Stack trace for your information.

```
   at System.IO.IsolatedStorage.IsolatedStorageFileStream..ctor(String path, FileMode mode, FileAccess access, FileShare share, Int32 bufferSize, IsolatedStorageFile isf)
   at System.IO.IsolatedStorage.IsolatedStorageFile.CreateFile(String path)
   at FXNews.Models.FFNewsProvider.SaveOrReplace(String fileContent)
   at FXNews.Models.FFNewsProvider.<Load>d__b.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter`1.GetResult()
   at FXNews.Models.FFNewsProvider.<GetNewsCollection>d__5.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter`1.GetResult()
   at FXNews.ViewModels.PivotPageViewModel.<GetAllNews>d__0.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter`1.GetResult()
   at FXNews.Views.PivotPage.<OnNavigatedTo>d__2.MoveNext()
```

What am I doing wrong in this case?

Answer (score 0):

Okay, after randomly fiddling around with the code I managed to get it right. In all honestly, I'm not sure the reasoning behind it, but it works.

```
public void SaveOrReplace(string fileContent)
{
    using (IsolatedStorageFile storage = IsolatedStorageFile.GetUserStoreForApplication())
    {
        if (!storage.DirectoryExists("FX"))
            storage.CreateDirectory("FX");

        if (storage.FileExists(FilePath))
            storage.DeleteFile(FilePath);

        using (IsolatedStorageFileStream fileStream = storage.OpenFile(FilePath, FileMode.CreateNew, FileAccess.Write, FileShare.Read))
        {
            using (StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(fileStream))
            {
                writer.Write(fileContent);
                writer.Dispose();
            }
            fileStream.Dispose();
        }

    }
}
```

and I changed my `FilePath`

```
private const string FilePath = "FX/ffcal.xml"; // does not work, throw a different exception after I did above changes
private const string FilePath = "FX/ffcal.txt"; // this works fine, save the xml in txt and parse it. It works okay
```